# What is the truly TRUE way to denote regression equation?

Tags: statistics, regression, linear-regression

I have seen a lot of books where statistics is not the focus denote the regression equation in the "proper" way, and I want to clear things up to ensure my understanding. Is it true that:

1. The predicted regression equation (i.e. the one that software spits out; the best guessed line of fit) is denoted $\hat{y} = \hat{b_1}x +\hat{b_0}$.
2. The actual, as-seen-in-the-collected-data value is $y$, and thus the absolute true regression equation that we would arrive at if we were God or something would be $y = b_1 x + b_0$.
3. In order to arrive at $y$ using our prediction line, we add *some value* $\varepsilon$ which is not constant because it depends on which prediction you're adjusting. Generally, to arrive at one of your true data points then $y = \hat{b_1} x + \hat{b_0} + \varepsilon$. I'm thinking about all those dots that may be above or below the best fit line: at any point on that best fit line, we need to move vertically up or down to reach our actual number. Sometimes $\varepsilon$ is zero because our best fit line passes right through $y$.
4. There is no difference between $\varepsilon$ and $\hat{\varepsilon}$ in statement 3. You are not attempting to predict the error (it arrives from an attempt to predict $y$ in the first place), so technically $\varepsilon$ is most correct.

Comment: I’m not sure of your exact setup.  Perhaps you have data points $(x_i, y_i)$ for $i \in \{1, …, m\}$ and you want to find $a,b$ such that $ay_i+b$ is a pretty good estimator of $x_i$ across all of the data, so that  $\sum_{i=1}^m (ay_i+b - x_i)^2$ is minimized. In that case, if you want,  you can define $\epsilon_i = ay_i+b - x_i$ as the error between the true value $x_i$ and its linearized estimate, so you want to  choose real numbers $a,b$ to minimize the sum of squared errors $\sum_{i=1}^m \epsilon_i^2$.

Comment: If you think of $(x_i,y_i)$ for $i \in \{1, ..., m\}$ as "ground truth" training data then you can use the coefficients $a,b$ that are optimized from the training data to estimate the value of $x$ in a new vector $(x,y)$ based only on observing $y$, by forming the estimate $\hat{x}(y)=ay+b$.  If $(x,y)$ is generated according to a model that is similar to the training data, there is hope that $\hat{x}(y)$ is close to $x$.

Comment: (1). I am used to referring to $\hat{y}_n=\hat{a}+\hat{b}x_n$ as the prediction equation. This is because you can use it to give the best estimate of $y_k$ given $x_k$ and your coefficients estimates.

(2). The equation $y_n=a+bx_n+\varepsilon_n$ is also referred to as the data-generating process. Still semantics. Divine beings can see it though.

(3-4). Given $\hat{y}_n=\hat{a}+\hat{b}x_n$, you obtain $y_n$ by adding up $\hat{\varepsilon}_n=y_n-\hat{y}_n$. Mind $\hat{\varepsilon}$ and $\varepsilon$ are different things: the former is a numerical value, the latter is random variable.

Comment: The whole question is ambiguous because no criteria of fitting is specified. They are as many different "proper ways" than they are different criteria of fitting (LMSE, LMRSE, LMAE, etc.). Thinking that a unique "proper way" exists without specifying what exactly is  the goal for the regression is non-sens.